# Routing outbound http traffic through "external" router

Tags: linux, routes, firewall, iptables, netfilter

I have two linux VPS servers with one "public" network interface each. I want to route all http traffic going out from Server 1 through the proxy serving on Server 2 (on port 8080).

I don`t want to configure the client applications on Server 1, rather I want to use networking magic to make it work in general for all applications making request with destination port 80.

How do I do this?

Comment: Have a look to iptables